# How to install EFPowerTool Beta on the right version of VS on my PC

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-power-tools

I have several versions of MS Visual Studio installed on my PC. VS 2010, VS Express 2012 for Web and WebMatrix 2. The problem I am having is that when I try to install EFPowerTool Beta (Entity Framework Power Tool)(vsix file) on VS Express 2012 for Web to use in my ASP.NET MVC project; the MS Visual Studio version selector selects VS 2010 and installs it on that IDE. Do you have any solution on how to install EFPowertool on VS Express 2012 for Web? I'm clueless?

Answer (score 3):

According to vsixmanifest files you need at least Pro versions of VS2010 or VS2012 to install the EF Power Tools Beta. You can try to hack it (No guarantees - I have not tried):

1) Add .zip extension to the vsix file. (vsix is actually a zip file)

2) Unpack the zip file to a folder

3) Open vsixmanifest file

4) Modify the file so that  this fragment:

```
<VisualStudio Version="11.0">
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
</VisualStudio>
```

looks as follows:

```
<VisualStudio Version="11.0">
  <Edition>Express_All</Edition>   
  <Edition>Pro</Edition>
</VisualStudio>
```

5) Zip the folder back

6) Rename zip to vsix

7) Double click the vsix file to install

Again, this is a hack. Even if it allows you to install the extension on the Visua Express for Web it does not mean everything (or anything) will work. But still - it takes only 10 minutes to try.

Comment: Not helpful for me. I have done exactly what u suggested but not able to install to my vs2012 express.