# How to install VSIX (visual studio extention) from local drive to a specific version of VS when multiple version of VS are installed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Rather simple thing that got me stumbled. I have a VSIX file I'd like to add to VS2012. I also have VS2010 run on the same box. After poking menus for a `Browse` button, I just run the file  by double clicking on it. It got installed but into VS2010. Is there a way to install it to VS2012? Is VSIX file VS version specific and I need to get VS2012 specific VSIX?

Answer (score 1):

VSIX files contain .vsixmanifest file that tells what versions of VS are supported. You can see the manifest if you open the vsix file - it is a zip file so you can change/append the extension so it's zip to open it. You can try hack to install it for VS2012. See: [How to install EFPowerTool Beta on the right version of VS on my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441728/how-to-install-efpowertool-beta-on-the-right-version-of-vs-on-my-pc/13444395#13444395)