# Visual Studio 2012 Express with Entity Framework menu

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS 2012 beta version and then installed Entity framework following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx) and it worked fine.

VS 2012 beta expired so i got VS 2012 Express. I tried to follow the same tutorial but now i don't have "Entity Framework Reverse Engineer Code First" in right-click project menu.

Is it a limitation in Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Power Tools are not available on Express SKU - you need at least Pro version. See this thread for more detailed answer: [How to install EFPowerTool Beta on the right version of VS on my PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441728/how-to-install-efpowertool-beta-on-the-right-version-of-vs-on-my-pc)